# How to Extract all records from a MS Excel Table for 3 to 4 criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, find, database

I have a database of inventory items of a manufacturing unit. The headings of the table are :

```
Material_Name   Item_Code   Group_head  Sub_Head    Type_Head   Minor_Head  UOM
ABC                 1         CON         XXX          YYY          ZZZ
DEF                 2       RAWMAT        PPP          QQQ          R1
DEF                 2         CON         PPP          QQQ          RR1
```

How can I extract all rows from this database on the basis of 3 or 4 criteria out of the `Table Headings` described above with a `formula`?.
 When any criteria is changed by the user, the extract data must change automatically.

Kindly guide.

Comment: Can you show an example of the Data and your criteria?

Comment: Sample Data is under

Comment: Data Fields are                                                                                                        Material_Name Item_Code Group_head Sub_Head Type_Head Minor_Head      ABC                   001             CON             XXX          YYY              ZZZ               DEF                   002             RAWMAT      PPP          QQQ            R1

Comment: DATA IS AS UNDER                                                                                                       Material_Name Item_Code Group_head Sub_Head Type_Head Minor_Head      ABC                   001             CON             XXX          YYY              ZZZ               DEF                   002             CON             PPP          QQQ            RR1

Comment: Where is the criteria you have to explain

Comment: You can use filter and set each column for the criteria you need and copy the result to another sheet

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look into something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/run-sql-on-excel-table

In short, you want to run SQL queries on Excel datasets.